# Some questions about a "relaxed" invariant probability problem $|\mu(P-I)|\leq \epsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, markov-chains

Let's consider the set  $\mathcal{M}=\{\mu:|\mu(P-I)|_1\leq \epsilon\}$ where $\mu$ is a probability vector, $P$ is the transition matrix of a discrete homogeneous Markov chain, $I$ is the identity matrix, $|\cdot|_1$ is the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_of_probability_measures), and $\epsilon$ is a small positive constant.

In some sense, $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of probability vectors that are "almost" invariant with respect to the Markov chain given by $P$. I've tried to understand some property about this set.

Since it seems some sort of generalized eigenvector problem where one has some "bounded-error tolerance", I tried to look for some literature in numerical analysis about it, finding nothing.

First, any reference related to the object above would be really appreciated. 
Second, here is a specific question I tried to figure out: is $\mathcal{M}$ always the convex hull of a finite number of probability vectors? Checking that is convex is straightforward, but I didn't manage to prove that there is a finite number of "extremal" elements that generate $\mathcal{M}$ as their convex hull.